# Gradle tasks are not showing in the gradle tool window in Android Studio 4.2

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-studio-4.2

I just updated Android Studio to version 4.2. I was surprised to not see the Gradle tasks in my project.

In the previous version, 4.1.3, I could see the tasks as shown here:

[image: working in version 4.1.3]

But now I only see the dependencies in version 4.2:

[image: Not working in 4.2]

I tried to clear Android Studio's cache and sync my project again, but there was no change.

Is this a feature change?

Answer (score 388, accepted):

OK, I found why I got this behaviour in android studio 4.2.

It is intended behaviour. I found the answer in this post: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/185420705.

> Gradle task list is large and slow to populate in Android projects.
> This feature by default is disabled for performance reasons. You can
> re-enable it in: Settings | Experimental | Do not build Gradle task
> list during Gradle sync.

Reload the Gradle project by clicking the "Sync Project with gradle Files" icon and the tasks will appear.

It could be cool that this experimental change is put in the release note of android studio `4.2`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @vewert You can still run the tasks from command line, for example: `./gradlew app:dependencies`

Comment: Should this option stay unticked? Or do I do it once and get it back to what it was?

Comment: I was missing the JAVA_HOME environment variable on my (fresh) system, so I just had to install Java, and all worked as expected after performing the above.

Comment: I am on Android Studio Flamingo 2022.2.1 Patch 2, and that option is no longer displayed. Instead there is an option "Only include test tasks in the Gradle task list generated during Gradle sync", and my task list only includes test tasks

Answer (score 280):

Go to `File -> Settings -> Experimental` and uncheck `Do not build Gradle task list during Gradle sync`, then sync the project `File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`. If the problem is still there, just reboot Android Studio.

1.[image: Do not build Gradle task list during Gradle sync]

2.
[image]

Answer (score 38):

For **Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1** and later

*Update Jun 23rd 2023*: the same with **Android Studio Flamingo**

Go to Settings and **uncheck** this thing in below picture:

After that, **sync** your project again
[image]

---

UPDATE for **Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1**

Now, you have to **CHECK** the following option: (So annoying to the way they changed the UI)
[image]

Comment: Lost a lot of time until I found this tick. I don't understand how she got involved.

Comment: @Maxim can I ask you: who is "she"? "Electric Eel" :)

Comment: I don't understand who ticked the box. I didn't do it. I don't know English well, google translate failed) My IDE "Flamingo RC 2"

Comment: Maybe upgrading your Android Studio made it happen

Comment: @Tony I can't find the setting for Android Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1 patch 1

Comment: @KostadinGeorgiev check my post, I've just updated it

Answer (score 12):

**Solution 1:**

You can alternatively use the below gradle command to get all the tasks and run those in terminal

```
./gradlew tasks --all
```

**Solution 2.**

You can also create run configuration to run the tasks like below:

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2:

[image]

Step 3:

[image]

Then your run configuration will be listed like in step 1 image. You can choose and simply run it as usual.

Answer (score 8):

Inside your android studio, select File option in toolbar -> then click on Settings option.

1. From settings, select the last option "Experimental"
2. Within there, select **Uncheck the option** that I have shared the screenshot below.
3. Then click Apply.[image]

4. After that, Sync your project again from the file option, over their **Sync project with Gradle Files**

All set :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 6):

To check the task list use the below command

```
./gradlew task
```

You will get the list of available task. To execute a particular task run command as follow

```
./gradlew <taskname>
```

Answer (score 6):

This solution works for me

Go to File -> Settings -> Experimental and uncheck Do not build Gradle task list during Gradle sync, then sync the project File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and I solved it by executing the following terminal command in my Android Studio Terminal:

```
./gradlew tasks --all
```