# Gradle GUI shows only dependencies

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I want my gradle GUI to show tasks and not only dependencies. Look at the pictures. My gradle shows picture1 (with black background) and I want it to show tree like in picture2 (white background).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The disabling offline mode should resolve the problem:
[image]

**Update:**
[Gradle tasks are not showing in the gradle tool window in Android Studio 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67405791/gradle-tasks-are-not-showing-in-the-gradle-tool-window-in-android-studio-4-2)

Comment: Nope. I tried, but nothing changed

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67405791/gradle-tasks-are-not-showing-in-the-gradle-tool-window-in-android-studio-4-2